# Grails: Как сделать submit <g:formRemote> через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, submit, grails

Есть форма:

```
<g:formRemote id="formId" update="messageArea" url=[controller: "message,   action: "post">
<g:textArea/>
</g:formRemote>
```

Вызываю submit обычным JavaScript:

`document.getElementById('formId').submit()`

И AJAX не отправляется, `render` идет на новую страницу, а не в блок . А если использую вариант со скрытой `<g:submitButton/>` и её последующей активацией через JavaScript то все отлично, `render` посылает контент в блок, все работает как задумывалось.

Форма:

```
<g:formRemote id="formId" update="messageArea" url=[controller: "message,   action: "post">
<g:textArea/>
<g:submitButton id="updateMessageButton" value="Update" hidden="hidden"/>
</g:formRemote>
```

Скрипт:

`document.getElementById('updateMessageButton').submit()`

Вариант через простой `<button type="submit" form="formId">` так же не работает.

Интересны причины, почему происходит именно так. Что особенного в  (в доках ничего не нашел интересного, возможно не там смотрел). И как правильно сделать сабмит формы через JavaScript

Comment: `document.getElementById('updateMessageButton').submit()` не имеет ничего общего с Ajax-запросом.

Comment: И имеет смысл в вопросе указывать итоговой (отображаемый в браузере) HTML-код вместо всех этих `g:`

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете схитрить и просто нажать на кнопку отправки формы:

```
document.getElementById('updateMessageButton').click();
```